# React Error The requested URL was not found on this server when refreshing

Tags: html, reactjs

My React app works perfectly fine locally, but when I deploy it, routing does not work as it should. When I click on the navigation bar buttons everything works perfectly fine, but when I try to refresh or to write routes manually, I get the message "requested URL was not found on this server". It also says "Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." ,  even if I have an .htaccess file.

here is my code :

-here's one of the buttons in the Navigation Bar :

```
<Link to="/contact">
        <button>
          <FadeIn delay={200}>CONTACT</FadeIn>
        </button>
      </Link>
```

-here's the App.tsx file which includes the routing :

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"; 

function App() {
 return (
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path = "/" component={Carusel}/>
      <Route exact path = "/contact" component={Contact}/>
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</Router>
```

);
}

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your server isn't handling any route except `"/"`, which is fine while you're routing client-side, but making a request to `GET "/contact"` will fail.

As an example, a React app when uploaded as an AWS S3 bucket in website configuration will require you to set an error document. You can set this error document to be your index.html, so the 404 will be handled by your frontend app, which knows how to handle the route.

Here's an example in which the error document is set to index.html
https://andela.com/insights/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-to-aws-s3/

Answer (score 0):

Please update your .htaccess file with the following code and try.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
  </IfModule>
```